# Calculate the time difference, if value doesn't pass certain threshold and if time difference is in given interval print name

Tags: python, pandas, time, timedelta

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
+-------+------------+------+--------+
| Index |    Time    | Name | Weight |
+-------+------------+------+--------+
|     0 | 2016-01-31 | X    |     84 |  
|     1 | 2017-01-31 | X    |     80 | 
|     2 | 2018-01-31 | X    |     86 |  
|     3 | 2019-01-31 | X    |     82 | 
|     4 | 2016-01-31 | Y    |     84 |
|     5 | 2017-01-31 | Y    |     80 |  
|     6 | 2018-01-31 | Y    |     87 |
|     7 | 2019-01-31 | Y    |     90 |
|     8 | 2016-01-31 | Z    |     88 |
|     9 | 2017-01-31 | Z    |     92 |
|    10 | 2018-01-31 | Z    |     91 |
|    11 | 2019-01-31 | Z    |     92 |
+-------+------------+------+--------+
```

And I want to print distinct Name for only ones that its Weight <= 90 for minimum 2 years.

So the answer would be [X, Y] since;

X is below 90 for 4 years and,
Y is below 90 for 3 years from 2016 to 2018 and,
Z is failing because it's only below 90 in 2016.

I really can't get my head around figuring this out! Is there a way out for this? Any help will be much much appreciated!! Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do `rolling` `n` here is your thresh

```
n=2
s=(df['Weight']<90).groupby(df['Name']).rolling(n).sum().eq(n).groupby(level=0).any()
Name
 X         True
 Y         True
 Z        False
Name: Weight, dtype: bool
s.index[s]
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot ! Just to make sure, if my periods were in 6 months of time period rather then a year; does that means I have to make n=4 to get 2 years rolling right ?

Comment: I also wonder how s.index[s] returns only ones with True label? It will be much appreciated if you also could explain that.

Comment: @EgeÇıkrıkçı yes , rolling will two value in row have lower than 90 , for the 2nd question , that is bool index filter ~